# How to disable Offline and Away chat option in Live agent(Salesforce)

Tags: liveagent

Hello I am new to the world of salesforce and I was implementing Live agent in my project, I was trying to hide or disable the Offline and Away option from the Chat option. But unfortunately I didn't find any way to do this. Please help me in same, how can I do this